# The best extension to enable autocomplete feature when writing JavaScript in Atom

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-devtools, atom-editor

I'm learning Javascript and up until now when I wanted to change anything in the DOM, I was using Google Chrome devtools to do that. Now I'm moving to write my code inside the JavaScript file, that accompanies the webpage, in Atom but the problem is the extremely useful autocomplete features of Chrome devtools is not available in Atom. For example when I type this code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(){
  const mainHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
  mainHeading.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
})
```

Chrome devtools is intelligent enough to suggest `backgroundColor` with a capital C to prevent any typing errors but the same thing doesn't happen in Atom. In fact Atom does not have any suggestions at all. I have tried installing different JavaScript plugins such as atom-ternjs or autocomplete-javascript, to name a few but none is working when you want to write the code to manipulate the DOM. Any suggestions to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried saving your file with an extension? autocomplete-css and autocomplete-html are packages installed by default that likely only trigger on specific file types (i.e. .html and .css). If not, you should search for the right package.

Comment: Yes.. the file I'm talking about is JavaScript file as part of a package that includes a webpage written in HTML. So I've saved it as .js file as I think, I should have.

Comment: The most ironic part is that I am almost certain Atom uses the Chromium Project. Which is an open source of Google Chrome. If you press Ctrl + Shift + I in Atom, it actually opens the Inspect Element, the one from Google Chrome. Even if you don't have Chrome installed. Actually. I could actually probably make one. Actually, it would be very easy. Probably. You know what, I convinced myself to do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using [TabNine](https://www.tabnine.com/) extension now and I'm satisfied with the performance. It uses deep learning to learn and predict the variables and lines of code you might want to write based on those variables and the more lines you write in a particular project the better it gets at giving the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick solution using Atom Ternjs.
Navigate to the menu bar and click Packages-> Atom Ternjs -> Configure Project.
Here, select the browser option under libs
[image: browser]

Then, just scroll down and click on Save and Restart Server.
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer... I will certainly try this out

Comment: This is very helpful. Although, something that should be improved on is more information of what is happening in the images and what the other settings means as well to be more universally helpful.